# Second Noun in Python NLTK Grammar RegExParser Not Recognized

Tags: python, parsing, nltk, regexp-grammars

I have created the following code to recognize a grammar consisting of a verb folowed by one or more determiners and then one or more nouns.  The grammar will not recognize a second noun as being in the grammar (example phrase: "monitoring a parking space"):

```
Testing sentence in grammar:  monitoring a parking space
Grammar Chunk: 
(S (MT monitoring/VBG a/DT parking/NN) (MT space/NN))
False
```

Here is the code used in Python 3.5.6:

```
import nltk

def extractMT(sent):
    grammar = r"""
    MT:
        {<VBG|VBZ|VB>?<DT>?<NN|NNS>}
    """
    chunker = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)

    ne = set()
    chunk = chunker.parse(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent)))
    print("Grammar Chunk: ")
    print(chunk)

    for tree in chunk.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.label() == 'MT'):
        returnList = []
        for child in tree.leaves():
                returnList.append(child[0])

        ne.add(' '.join(returnList))

    return ne

testSentence1 = "monitoring a parking space"

print ("Testing sentence in grammar:  " + testSentence1)

print ("Is sentence in grammar?:  " + testSentence1 in extractMT(testSentence1))
```

Comment: like in `regex` add `+` or `*` to get more elements `{<VBG|VBZ|VB>?<DT>?<NN|NNS>+}`

Answer (score 0):

Like in standard `regex` to get many elements you need `+` (which means `one or more`) or `*` (which means `zero or more`)

```
 {<VBG|VBZ|VB>?<DT>?<NN|NNS>+}
```

You can also use `{,2}` to get `0`, `1` or `2` elements, or `{1,2}` get `1` or `2` elements, or `{2}` to get exactly `2` elements

```
 {<VBG|VBZ|VB>?<DT>?<NN|NNS>{,2}}
```